# OpenGL failed Creating basic Window

Tags: c++, linux, glfw

I'm trying to compile a basic OpenGL program on Ubuntu, but I got a runtime error, the window I created crash!

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>    
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLint WIDTH = 800 , HEIGH = 600;

int main ()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cerr << "GLFW initialization failed" << std::endl ; 
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1  ; 
    }
    //setup GLFW window properties
    //OpenGL version 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,GL_TRUE);    
    GLFWwindow *main_window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH,HEIGH,"TestWindow",NULL,NULL);
    if(!main_window)
    {
        std::cerr << "GLFW creation failed " << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1 ;
    }
    int bufferWidth,bufferHeight ;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(main_window,&bufferWidth,&bufferHeight); 
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(main_window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE ;  
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        glfwDestroyWindow(main_window);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1 ;
    }
    glViewport(0,0,bufferWidth,bufferHeight);
    // loop until window closed 
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(main_window));
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClearColor(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);``
        glfwSwapBuffers(main_window);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

This is the output i get:
[image]

i don't Know if it's related to my Graphic Card:

```
description: VGA compatible controller
product: GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: a1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
resources: irq:36 memory:cf000000-cfffffff memory:70000000-7fffffff memory:80000000-81ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Any explanation?

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and show a stack trace of what the program is doing when your WM says it is "not responding"?

Comment: "[`driver=nouveau`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_(software))" oof ouch owie your performance

Comment: @Botje , it hangs exactly at : ``GLFWwindow *main_window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH,HEIGH,"TestWindow",NULL,NULL);``

Comment: Surely it is stuck somewhere _inside_ glfw?

Comment: yes it crashes in `glfwCreateWindow`! even the debugger can't step over this call !

Comment: Step over and _then_ get a backtrace. There should be a package with debug symbols for glfw to help you with function names .